# Make executable visible to bash

Tags: 16.04, command-line, java, eclipse

I have executable : `/opt/Eclipse/eclipse` . I would like to run it from any path from terminal console. For this reason I create symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/Eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
```

But this not helped to run eclipse just buy typing ./eclipse from any location in terminal window. System not finds executable. I was expecting that system will find `eclipse` link in `/usr/bin`. Where is mistake in my thinking?

Comment: did you change the permission on it so users can execute it? Also you should not need to put ./eclipse that explicitly makes it the local path. you should just be able to type eclipse (just like you do not type ./ls or ./grep)

Comment: I can run it from /opt/Eclipse/ without problem and I'm single user

Comment: Run it with `eclipse` not `./eclipse`

Comment: to see if something is "accessible" as a command do "which <executable>" Example "which ls" will return /bin/ls, in your case "which eclipse" should return the path it finds it at. Also you could just add the /opt/Eclipse/ to your PATH instead of putting the symbolic link.

Comment: just run `eclipse` gives error `The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed..`

Comment: but `/usr/bin` is in my `PATH` - why system not finds link `eclipse`?

Answer (score 2):

Why even bother linking it? You can simply add `/opt/Eclipse` to your `PATH`. In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="/opt/Eclipse:$PATH"
```

and then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then you should just be able to run

```
eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple alternative solution with the .bashrc file

Instead of creating a symbolic link you can simply add an alias in your `.bashrc` file... To do this, you can start off by adding `alias eclipse='/file/pathway/to/executable'` to the bottom of your `.bashrc` file.  Then you can test this by running `source .bashrc` and `eclipse`...

Answer (score 0):

This indeed may be a bit suprising at first sight. `bash` (and other shells as well) maintains a *hash* to quickly find binaries in the `$PATH` when a user issues a command. The alternative would be to scan all those directories every single time a command is issued to figure out which is meant. And that's costly.

Under certain circumstances that *hash* is not properly updated. Read [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) (section `hash`) for the exact details.

You seem to have spotted such a rare case when the actual directory contents and the values in that *hash* are out of sync. A simple

```
hash -r
```

tells `bash` to rebuild its hash. This has to be done only once if you want to keep your current terminal window open. If you instead close and reopen the terminal window, this is not needed.